# Deactivate sidebar for AtBeginSection-slides

Tags: beamer, sectioning, sidebar

I have a beamer-project, where it's required to have a sidebar, but not for the `\AtBeginSection`-slides.

What i've tried is to look at the definition of the sidebar-theme (`kpsewhich beamerouterthemesidebar.sty`) and define a new, empty template that i can switch to locally in the `\AtBeginSection`-block. This does what i want, but it doesn't work locally. I get an error, if i include the `\setbeamertemplate` inside the `\AtBeginSection`-block.

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}

\useoutertheme[%
width=3cm,
height=1cm,
hideothersubsections,
]{sidebar}

% This works but disables sidebar globally
\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate{sidebar \beamer@sidebarside}{dummy}{}
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar \beamer@sidebarside}[dummy] % Comment out for local option
\makeatother

\AtBeginSection[]{
  % This throws an error:
  % \makeatletter
  % \setbeamertemplate{sidebar \beamer@sidebarside}[dummy]
  % \makeatother
  \begin{frame}
    {\thesection\\[.4ex]\insertsectionhead}
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\begin{frame}{Title}
  Some content
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Title}
  Some content
\end{frame}

\section{Second section}

\begin{frame}{Title}
  Some content
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Title}
  Some content
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a workaround by making the frame `[plain]` the sidebar gets hidden automatically.

So my `\AtBeginSection` looks like this:

```latex
\AtBeginSection{%
  {%
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
    \setbeamertemplate{background}{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[at=(current page.south east)]
        \shadedraw[shading=axis,
        left color=left,
        right color=right,
        shading angle=135,
        middle color=right,
        vertical custom shading=40
        ]
        (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
        \fill[white] (\paperwidth,\paperheight) rectangle (\paperwidth-30.5mm,0);
        \node at (\paperwidth-1.8cm,4cm) {\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{Titelfolie}};
        \node at (\paperwidth-1.6cm,\paperheight-.7cm) {\includegraphics[width=2.2cm]{Hochschule-esslingen}};
        \node[font=\Huge, text=white, scale=1.5, align=left, text width=7cm] at (\paperwidth-9.5cm,\paperheight-5cm) {\thesection\\\MakeUppercase\insertsectionhead};
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }

    \begin{frame}<article:0>[plain]

    \end{frame}
  }
}
```